# Vectorizing min and max of slices possible?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Suppose that I have a NumPy array of integers.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000)
```

And I have two arrays `lower` and `upper`, which represent lower and upper bounds respectively on slices of `arr`. These intervals are overlapping and variable-length, however `lowers` and `uppers` are both guaranteed to be non-decreasing.

```
lowers = np.array([0, 5, 132, 358, 566, 822])
uppers = np.array([45, 93, 189, 533, 800, 923])
```

I want to find the min and the max of each slice of `arr` defined by `lowers` and `uppers`, and store these in another array.

```
out_arr = np.empty((lowers.size, 2))
```

**What is the most efficient way to do this**? I'm worried there is not a vectorized approach, as I can't see how I get around indexing in a loop..

---

My current approach is just the straightforward

```
for i in range(lowers.size):
    arr_v = arr[lowers[i]:uppers[i]]
    out_arr[i,0] = np.amin(arr_v)
    out_arr[i,1] = np.amax(arr_v)
```

which leaves me with a desired result like

```
In [304]: out_arr
Out[304]: 

array([[  26.,  908.],
       [  18.,  993.],
       [   0.,  968.],
       [   3.,  999.],
       [   1.,  998.],
       [   0.,  994.]])
```

but this is far too slow on my actual data.

Comment: How many slices, esp compared to the size of `arr`?  Looks like they vary in length? And they can overlap?  About the only way around such a iteration is to use a `accumulate`.  `cumsum` for example works in some cases, such as for slice sum and means.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, they are of variable length, overlapping, and for an array of approx 10^7 elements there are approx 10^5 slices. These are all inputs I'm reading from a db as well, so I don't think there isn't any space for a "better first step" before this.

Comment: `np.minimum.reduceat` might be applicable. It's a bit finicky because one would have to mix upper and lower limits. Also ultimately one would only reduce the problem to the same kind with a smaller array of values. But might still be worth it.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't quite understand how `accumulate` could be used for these slices of the array... doesn't it provide a running max? How would we establish a left boundary for our slice while using it? I'm playing with `reduceat` now.

Comment: How many times do you call this function?  If you're calling it frequently, it might be worth the overhead of using numba; just calling @jit on your straightforward solution cut the post-jit time from 2.3s to 0.08s for me.

Comment: @DSM Oh that is super helpful, thank you! I came up with a solution using `reduceat` on both the minimum and maximum as well, and it is not as fast as using numba though it is much quicker nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is how to at least down-size the original problem using `np.minimum.reduceat`:

```
lu = np.r_[lowers, uppers]
so = np.argsort(lu)
iso = np.empty_like(so)
iso[so] = np.arange(len(so))
cut = len(lowers)
lmin = np.minimum.reduceat(arr, lu[so])
for i in range(cut):
    print(min(lmin[iso[i]:iso[cut+i]]), min(arr[lowers[i]:uppers[i]]))

# 33 33
# 7 7
# 5 5
# 0 0
# 3 3
# 7 7
```

What this doesn't achieve is getting rid of the main loop but at least the data were reduced from a 1000 element array to a 12 element one.

Update:

With small overlaps @Eric Hansen's own solutions are hard to beat. I'd still like to point out that if there are substantial overlaps then it may even be worthwhile to combine both methods. I don't have `numba`, so below is just a twopass version that combines my preprossing with Eric's pure `numpy` solution which also serves as a benchmark in the form of `onepass`:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def twopass(lowers, uppers, arr):
    lu = np.r_[lowers, uppers]
    so = np.argsort(lu)
    iso = np.empty_like(so)
    iso[so] = np.arange(len(so))
    cut = len(lowers)
    lmin = np.minimum.reduceat(arr, lu[so])
    return np.minimum.reduceat(lmin, iso.reshape(2,-1).T.ravel())[::2]

def onepass(lowers, uppers, arr):
    mixture = np.empty((lowers.size*2,), dtype=lowers.dtype) 
    mixture[::2] = lowers; mixture[1::2] = uppers
    return np.minimum.reduceat(arr, mixture)[::2]

arr = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000)
lowers = np.array([0, 5, 132, 358, 566, 822])
uppers = np.array([45, 93, 189, 533, 800, 923])

print('small')
for f in twopass, onepass:
    print('{:18s} {:9.6f} ms'.format(f.__name__, 
                                     timeit(lambda: f(lowers, uppers, arr),
                                            number=10)*100))

arr = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10**6)
lowers = np.random.randint(0, 8*10**5, 10**4)
uppers = np.random.randint(2*10**5, 10**6, 10**4)
swap = lowers > uppers
lowers[swap], uppers[swap] = uppers[swap], lowers[swap]


print('large')
for f in twopass, onepass:
    print('{:18s} {:10.4f} ms'.format(f.__name__, 
                                     timeit(lambda: f(lowers, uppers, arr),
                                            number=10)*100))
```

Sample run:

```
small
twopass             0.030880 ms
onepass             0.005723 ms
large
twopass               74.4962 ms
onepass             3153.1575 ms
```

Comment: thanks Paul, this is great. I adapted a solution using your `reduceat` suggestion and added an answer myself with it, but I'm going to test this out and if its comparable I'll mark your answer as accepted as you gave me the idea.

Answer (score 1):

An improved version of my original attempt I came up with based on Paul Panzer's suggestion of `reduceat` is

```
mixture = np.empty((lowers.size*2,), dtype=lowers.dtype) 
mixture[::2] = lowers; mixture[1::2] = uppers

np.column_stack((np.minimum.reduceat(arr, mixture)[::2],
                 np.maximum.reduceat(arr, mixture)[::2]))
```

On a sample size comparable to my actual data, this runs in 4.22 ms on my machine compared to my original solution taking 73 ms.

Even faster though is to just use Numba with my original solution

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def get_res():
    out_arr = np.empty((lowers.size, 2))
    for i in range(lowers.size):
        arr_v = arr[lowers[i]:uppers[i]]
        out_arr[i,0] = np.amin(arr_v)
        out_arr[i,1] = np.amax(arr_v)
    return out_arr
```

which runs in 100 microseconds on my machine.

Comment: If anyone sees anything abhorrently wrong here, please let me know!

Comment: Neat. I'm always forgetting that one can go backwards with `reduceat`. Merely out of interest because that numba solution is incredibly fast. If you don't mind my asking. How large are your inputs? Is it the 10^7 / 10^5 you mention somewhere else? And how large is the overlap of your segments (say, total segment length over data length)?

Comment: The overlap from one interval to the next is about 80% of the total length of each interval... I came back to say that upon further benchmarking your NumPy approach is faster than mine for my interval overlaps it appears. Marking as accepted :)

Comment: A pleasure doing business with you ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The execution will be slow since inside the loop, the sub array is copied to an array and then the operations are carried out.  You can avoid the entire loop by single line code

```
out_array = np.array([(np.amin(arr[lowers[i]:uppers[i]]),np.amax(arr[lowers[i]:uppers[i]])) for i in range(lowers.size)])
```